# How does one populate a dropdown listview in c# with both and integer and a boolean expression with the following values

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want a listview containing the following weights =

- 1 Kg
- 3 Kg
- 5 Kg
- 10 Kg
- >10 Kg

Here is my attempt:

```
 private void weightList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int [] weights = { 1, 3, 5, 10, >10 };
        foreach (int theWeight in weights)
        {
            weightList.Items.Add(theWeight);
                }
```

//  How do I use the boolean expression ">" with the integers?

Comment: > is Boolean expression ??

Comment: use string[] instead of int[] and add ">10" to list

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!  -Waht is a 'dropdown listview'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `>10` integer. From what you have here it seems that you really need an `enum`:

```
public enum
{
  Kg_1,
  Kg_3,
  Kg_5,
  Kg_10,
  Kg_11+
}
```

You won't be able though to put those directly in any listview I suppose and will need a method that will convert them to a user-friendly string. But you will be able to get values (most likely) back as this enum and use it without parsing.

Details depends of course on what type of listview you have and where you use it, but the fact are, you can't use integer `>10` anywhere, since it's not valid in C#. You can always use ordinary string of course, but then you most likely will need some parsing, etc. while enum constraints the number of available elements.